# Static route in initramfs

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, static-routes, initramfs, busybox

My hosting provider unfortunately requires the use of static routes for network configuration (gateway is on a different subnet than the host IP). For that purpose I added the following lines to the network configuration file (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
post-up route add -host 172.31.1.1 dev ens3 && route add default gw 172.31.1.1
```

To unlock an encrypted root drive with cryptsetup I install dropbear, so that I can SSH into a busybox to provide the encryption password. I haven't found a way, however, to add static routes in the initramfs configuration file. Does anyone have an idea how this could be accomplished? The server in question is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did this worked? I tried it and doesn't get an IP adress.
Was this done (maybe) with a Hetzner Root Server oder a Cloud Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu full disc encryption on Hetzner Cloud adding add static route in initramfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/915118/ubuntu-full-disc-encryption-on-hetzner-cloud-adding-add-static-route-in-initramf)

Answer (score 0):

Create a little helper script that configures your static routing. According to [the initramfs-tools manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools.8.en.html)  scripts in /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs-premount are executed after the network interface has been enabled, but you may need to place the script in another sub directory.

You'll need to use `ip route` syntax because AFAIK the older `route` command won't be available:

```
#!/bin/sh 
# /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs-premount/static-routes

ip route add default via 172.31.1.1 dev ens3 

exit 0
```

and ensure that the script is executable (`chmod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/nfs-premount/static-routes`) before running `update-initramfs`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the route via initramfs script doesn't worked. Doesn't know why not.

An answer in another thread worked: [Ubuntu full disc encryption on Hetzner Cloud adding add static route in initramfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/915118/ubuntu-full-disc-encryption-on-hetzner-cloud-adding-add-static-route-in-initramf)

Open the file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions`, search the `configure_networking()` (around line 412 on Ubuntu 18.04) function and add the following directly before the closing `}`:

```sh
ip route add ${IPV4GATEWAY}/${IPV4NETMASK} dev ${DEVICE}
ip route add default via ${IPV4GATEWAY} dev ${DEVICE}
```

```sh
diff -p /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/functions{.orig,}
*** ./functions.orig    2019-03-27 14:00:57.685412556 +0000
--- ./functions 2019-03-27 13:59:09.758130638 +0000
*************** configure_networking()
*** 410,415 ****
--- 410,418 ----
                /run/net-${DEVICE}.conf /run/net-*.conf /run/net6-*.conf
        netinfo_to_netplan /run/netplan \
                /run/net-${DEVICE}.conf /run/net-*.conf /run/net6-*.conf
+
+         ip route add ${IPV4GATEWAY}/${IPV4NETMASK} dev ${DEVICE}
+         ip route add default via ${IPV4GATEWAY} dev ${DEVICE}
  }

  netinfo_to_resolv_conf() {
```